# After enabling folder redirection, office locks up autosaving

Tags: windows-server-2008, microsoft-office-2010, folder-redirection

After distributing folder redirection through group policy to about 10 desktops, users are complaining that Office, specifically Word, is locking up when AutoSaving their documents.  I believe this is because it has to be written to a network drive every few minutes.  I know it would be easy to move this location, but I would ideally take a different route...  I imagine that the file would be saved locally, and when the computer is not being used it would sync to the network drive.  Is there an option where the file does not need to IMMEDIATELY be stored on the server?

Comment: Things like this are why I am not a fan of folder redirection.

Comment: right after you implement folder redir the entire contents of the redirected folders is copied to the share being redirected to so network traffice could be saturating the server.

Comment: Thanks Tony,  I've only got ten workstations in the GPO now, and I set this up a few days ago, all seem to run through the Sync routine in about 10 minutes.  Is there another explanation?

Comment: did you configure CSC (client side caching)?

Comment: whats the workstation version?

Comment: btw at my previous site we had 18K users all using folder redir with csc, there were initial problems that were all related to poor network configurations. After that it work perfectly and if i remember correctly you need to exclude the csc dir from av scanning.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Offline Files](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff183315%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Also, you could add the auto-save file types (*.asd) into the Exclusion List, but I don't know if that's something you'd want to do.